# Need explanation for an expression '<[^<>]+>' in Octave

Tags: regex, octave

There is an expression in Octave as shown below

```
string1 = regexprep (string1, '<[^<>]+>', 'replacement');
```

I have run the above code and it replaces a substring in string1 that starts with '<' and ends with '>' with the 'replacement' string

I need further explanation as to how it works though.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html is a good place to start in general.

In this case,
`<` matches a literal opening angle bracket
`[^<>]` is a class (`[]` encloses a class) that matches anything that's not (`^` at the start of a class means not in the class) an angle bracket
`+` means match one or more of the previous thing (so: the whole string of not-angle-brackets you find)
and
`>` is the final closing angle bracket.

All of this is then replaced with the replacement string.